# I couldn't create .htaccess redirect

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

From `/etiket/(any page)` to `/konu/(any page)`.
How can I do it? In `.htaccess` file.

I searched and applied it but couldn't.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^etiket\/\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/konu\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the redirect in the wrong place. It must go *before* the WordPress front-controller, otherwise, it will never execute.

You should avoid editing between the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment tags, otherwise, your customisations could be overwritten in a future update.

You also have a lot of unnecessary escaping (eg. no need to escape colons, slashes and dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*). Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^etiket/(.*) https://example.com/konu/$1 [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Only change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK to avoid any caching issues.

NB: The `RewriteEngine On` directive only needs to be included once in the file. And this can literally go *anywhere* in the file, so you can leave the WordPress block of directives as they are.